# Mark current position in a doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
typedef struct tape
{
    char symbol;
    struct tape *next;
    struct tape *prev;
}tape;

tape *pt;

void ShowCurrentCombination()
{
    tape currentNode;


    currentNode = *pt;
    while(pt->prev != NULL)
            pt=pt->prev;

    while(pt->next != NULL)
        {
            if(pt == &currentNode) //this is never true :( 
            putc("[q]",stdout); 

            putc(pt->symbol,stdout);
                pt=pt->next;
        }
    putc(pt->symbol,stdout);
}
```

This function should show the content of list marking the current element by "[q]" at it's left side. Unfortunately, only the plain data is shown. Why?

For sake of completeness, let me introduce the function that initializes the list:

```
void GenerateInputTape(int n)
{
    int i;

    pt=(tape*)malloc(sizeof(tape));

    pt->symbol='B';

    pt->prev=NULL;
    pt->next=(tape*)malloc(sizeof(tape));
    pt->next->prev = pt;
    pt=pt->next;

    for(i=0;i<2*n+1;i++)
    {   
        if(i < (2*n/2))
            pt->symbol='0';
        else
            pt->symbol='1';


        pt->next=(tape*)malloc(sizeof(tape));
        pt->next->prev = pt;
        pt=pt->next;
    }

    pt->symbol='B';
    pt->next=NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check `pt == &currentNode` you check if `pt` points to `currentNode`. This never happens, since `currentNode` is not even in the list (no element in the list points to it).

You want `currentNode` not to be a copy, but pointer equal to `pt` at the beginning of function.

```
tape *currentNode;
currentNode = pt;
...
if(pt == currentNode)
```

You also don't check the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Note the relation between

```
currentNode = *pt;
```

and

```
if(pt == &currentNode)
```

In the first, you have initialized `currentNode` with *the contents* of what the pointer `pt` *points to*.  In the second, you are checking if the *address* of `currentNode` is the same as that of some member in the list (pointed to by `pt`).  It should be clear why this can never be true.

What you need to do is to save the address, i.e. the pointer, not its contents

```
tape *currentNodePointer = pt;
```

and later

```
if(pt == currentNodePointer)
```

(Your code could be organized better to obviate having always to "rewind" to the head of the list, but that's for another day perhaps.)